# Ubuntu 16.04 constantly freezing leading to kernel panic

Tags: kernel, 16.04

I had issues with my laptop constantly freezing. So I found a post where someone had suggested updating the kernel to remedy the issue. I followed the steps outlined here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/789092/542662

The end result of this is my system going into kernel panic every time I try to turn it on. I'm not even sure as to how to try to fix this or install a fresh version of Ubuntu 16.04 at this point.

Comment: Try what Zanna said and said. Also release candidate (RC) versions are not fully tested and should only be used by experts. If your laptop freezes one thing you should do is check video drivers. 16.04 is known to have regression problems with video drivers. Some have been sold by updates iirc but not all. You ll need to check the situation specifically with your GPU model.

Comment: @akaironin I am facing exact same situation and I ran into same problem after updating kernal. Had you found any solution for this?