# 16.04 LTS constantly freezes and no sound

Tags: 16.04

Ever since the upgrade my instance of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS screen keeps on freezing, I have no mouse or keyboard interaction, and the only way to get out of it, is to restart. Also, I have lost sound.

Doing my own research into the matter has failed to find a solution, and I was wondering whether anyone has suffered the same, but who has a solution to share.

Comment: System specs please?

Comment: Check out http://askubuntu.com/questions/761706/ubuntu-15-10-and-16-04-keep-freezing-randomly/789092#789092. Chances are it's driver related.