# Random freezes in Ubuntu 16.04 on Dell Inspiron 11 3147

Tags: 16.04, dell, inspiron

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS freezes randomly when running on Dell Inspiron 11 3147 (2016) laptop.
Mouse, keyboard, touchscreen are not reacting - I have to power cycle the machine.

This happens both on stock configuration (4GB RAM, 500GB HDD) and after upgrade (8GB RAM, Samsung 850 Evo SSD).

Resource monitor shows CPU, RAM and storage are used reasonably, all well below 30%.
I have upgraded the kernel to version 4.6.4, the problem still exists.

I can not blame hardware, as Windows 10 (which was originally coming with the laptop) had worked non-stop for weeks with no problems at all.

In `/var/log/syslog` I can not see anything which could explain a sudden freeze, however, I might be overlooking something or searching in a wrong direction.
Could you give me some hints how can I resolve this?

UPDATE: I have installed Gnome as my new default window manager. At the moment machine runs smoothly for several hours.

Comment: This is a common issue with the inspiron 3147. Updating the linux kernel to 4.7 will definatly solve your random freeze problem. Here is a link on how to update the kernel. https://askubuntu.com/questions/761706/ubuntu-15-10-and-16-04-keep-freezing-randomly There are other ways besides this to update to kernel 4.7. Google how to update ubuntu 16.04 to linux kernel 4.7 if the link doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar freezes with ssd samsung 850 pro.

Some SSDs are blacklisted as they dont work with linux.

Samsung seem to be in the blacklist.

I too am disappointed. The thought of using a spindle drive.... yuk!

You can search for blacklisted SSDs and try and buy one thats not in the list as an alternate?

I tried putting in the following

sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

then modifying this line to result in this line

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="libata.force=noncq"

then updated the grub loader via

sudo update-grub2

However that didnt always fix the problem. The first time I installed it was fine and then on reboot froze now and again.

Answer (score 0):

Update to linux kernel 4.7 to solve random freeze issue

Run these in terminal

wget http://in4serv.com.br/backup/kernel-4.7.1

sudo chmod +x kernel-4.7.1

./kernel-4.7.1

Then update grup

sudo update-grub

sudo reboot

Now if this does not work for you google other methods of updating to the kernel 4.7