# fresh Ubuntu 16.04. Mouse and Keybord freeze every 1 seconds of inactivity

Tags: mouse

Fresh Ubuntu 16.04. USB mouse and keybord working on my desktop.

After installing list of packages mouse and keybord freeze every 1 seconds of inactivity (two different mouses, two different keyboards), and waking up after first click or press.

List of commands (no other changes in the system I made manually):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get install vlc htop brasero clementine gdebi synaptic preload prelink laptop-mode-tools gedit bleachbit screenfetch
```

This problem repeated after reinstall distribution.

What I tried:

- [Edit the `/etc/default/grub` file and change the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line to add the usbcore.autosuspend=-1 option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/175035/70856)
- [Updating the kernel](https://askubuntu.com/a/789092/233352)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like package "laptop-mode-tools" is guilty. I just reinstall distribution and omit this package, and till now everything is ok.

Comment: That was my hunch too before reading your answer. Thanks for sharing.