# Ubuntu 16.04 Randomly Crashes... I've tried most "fixes"

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, intel, freeze, crash

My computer freezes at seemingly random times. It usually freezes 1-2 times a day now. This has been going on for a month now. The computer becomes completely inaccessible and I can't get out of the freeze through Alt+sysreq+F (none of the other combinations work either like REISUB, etc.). I have to

- I've tried the "intel_idle.max_cstate=1" fix. It doesn't work.
  [Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04 keep freezing randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761706/ubuntu-15-10-and-16-04-keep-freezing-randomly?rq=1)
- I've looked at psensor and it is always within very reasonable levels.
- I keep the system monitor up and it's always within very reasonable levels.
- I've installed all the updates recommended by my computer.

Some other issues I've had include the following. Maybe it will help diagnose my issue.

- Running jupyter notebook takes about a minute to startup (that's super long).
- Computer takes a long time to startup.
- Desktop background on nice 4k monitor always displays incorrectly at startup.

Computer information...

- Kernal version: 4.7.0-040700rc3-generic
- [My computer hardware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oP5s1.png)
- [var/log/ at the point where it crashes!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDV4Z.png)

I honestly have no idea why it keeps crashing. My guess is that it may have to do with my graphics? Anyone have any insight? Or some direction in fixing this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Did you use smartmontools and badblocks to check the hard disk ? Did you maybe find something interesting in the log files ? e.g. in kern.log and syslog in /var/log/ Can you check the RAM memory by booting from a Linux live-cd and then run a memtest86 test for at least 5 to 10 minutes, preferably much longer ?

Comment: === START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED. I'm looking at the others right now as well. Thanks

Comment: Okay, good. I like to suggest to let smartctl run a long test, for example if your hdd device is /dev/sda :   sudo smartctl --test=long /dev/sda  Note that it will tell you the estimated time it needs, after you execute the command. It will do the test in the background, and might take quite a while.

Comment: @albertj I've added an image of the var/log/ at which my computer crashes. I know the issue is not with the labels above because that is just a recent change I made (issue occurred before that started). I'm going to run through the memory test tomorrow after the smartctl test.  thanks

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes