# Ubuntu Freezes randomly

Tags: grub2, freeze, mate, ubuntu-mate

I am using Ubuntu Mate . when i run more apps the mouse courser stop moving and the whole system freeze with no response till i turn off my device. 
i searched about this problem and tried to update my kernel (when i was using Ubuntu desktop version with unity) but there was no improvement.
i read this [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/796484/568353) and i want to ask if this line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1" will work on my hp device as there is (intel) in the code line?!

update 1 : my processor is :AMD E1-1200 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2

Comment: Your HP computer might have an Intel processor in it, so it's possible that will work. Try it out.

Comment: my processor is : AMD E1-1200 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics × 2

Comment: That kernel parameter won't help you then. How much RAM do you have? How much swap?

Comment: i dont use  swap  partition
my RAM : 4 gb

Comment: There's your problem. You need swap, esp with only 4G RAM.

Comment: i had read that making a swap partition will harm my hard disk .. what do u think?

Comment: Do you use an SSD? Do you have a HDD on the system?

Comment: i tried a command to know what is the type of my hard disk showing me that i use HDD

Comment: Swap will not hurt your HDD. Install a swap partition, mkswap, and edit /etc/fstab. I'd recommend 8G swap.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

As the user starts more apps, the system freezes. They only have 4G RAM and no swap.

Recommend creating a 8G swap partition, mkswap, lsblk, edit /etc/fstab, swapon -a, to make a working swap. If you need specific instructions, please ask.

example `/etc/fstab` entry:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=071f8b0e-8e16-4f4d-90ff-a4ae9cc56e2b   none   swap   sw   0   0
```

Comment: Please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful.