# Random freezes occurring with Ubuntu 16.10: Dell Inspiron 11-3168

Tags: dell, 16.10, crash

I recently purchased a Dell Inspiron 11-3168, which came preinstalled with Windows 10, which I installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside.

I haven't used the windows partition as extensively as I have the Ubuntu partition, but as far as I can tell, this seems to be an issue with Ubuntu. I even ran both the windows memory diagnostic tool, memtest86, and dell's hardware diagnostic tool to confirm that this isn't a hardware issue, and nothing came up.

What happens is that (usually while I'm on google chrome and have a youtube video on in the background, though that's usual, so I'm not sure how relevant that is) my system will randomly crash -- ctrl-alt-F1 doesn't work, REISUB doesn't do anything, I have to power cycle it to get it to shut down.

I found someone having a [similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761706/ubuntu-15-10-and-16-04-keep-freezing-randomly) in Ubuntu 16.04 (which I've also tried using -- has the same issue) on a similar model that was solved by updating the kernel, but I've tried a number of the recent kernels (4.8-4.10) and nothing seems to solve the problem.

I'd like to know what the best way to diagnose my problem would be, or even better, if this is a known issue with this model of Inspirons, and what the workaround is. (The closest thing I could find in a google search was the linked askubuntu question)

Edit: Also, an important thing about this that I should mention is that if I just had one of these crashes and try rebooting, there is a good chance that it will happen again shortly after booting up.