# Random freezes in Ubuntu 16.04 due to mouse and keyboard devices being ignored

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, xorg, mouse, evdev

I have the same problem as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761706/ubuntu-15-10-and-16-04-keep-freezing-randomly) but not enough reputation to comment or answer. Also I've read related questions / solutions.

**I'm experiencing random freezes unrelated to a specific activity - sometimes just typing in a terminal. Mouse and keyboard are completely unresponsive but display does refresh. Also ssh sessions continue to work fine.**

Initial install was 14.04 where there were no problems. 
Freezes didn't start immediately after the 16.04 upgrade but many months later (can't tell precisely when anymore) suggesting it's a software issue.

As suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761706/ubuntu-15-10-and-16-04-keep-freezing-randomly) and other places I've tried

- moving mouse / keyboard to a different usb port
- upgrading kernel to 4.10, 4.10.rc7, 4.11.rc7 including missing i915 modules to no help
- enabling / disabling additional drivers
- checked swap is enabled
- done the `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` trick
- `lightdm restart`does does not restore mouse and keyboard
- reinstall `xserver-xorg`
- reinstall `xserver-xorg-input-evdev`
- [complete reinstall of xserver](https://www.computersnyou.com/4945/re-install-xorg-xserver-completely-ubuntu/)
- using the HWE suite `sudo apt install xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04`

I've checked syslog, kern.log, .xsession-errors, Xorg.0.log. 60s after the freeze and every 60 seconds thereafter I'm seeing the following in Xorg.0.log:

```
[ 94823.921] (II) config/udev: removing device Logitech USB Optical Mouse
[ 94823.940] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Close
[ 94823.940] (II) UnloadModule: "evdev"
[ 94825.607] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[ 94825.607] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 94825.607] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 94825.707] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Logitech USB Optical Mouse (/dev/input/event4)
[ 94825.707] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[ 94825.707] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech USB Optical Mouse'
[ 94825.707] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: always reports core events
[ 94825.707] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[ 94825.764] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Vendor 0x46d Product 0xc077
[ 94825.764] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found 12 mouse buttons
[ 94825.764] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found scroll wheel(s)
[ 94825.764] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found relative axes
[ 94825.764] (--) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Found x and y relative axes
[ 94825.764] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Configuring as mouse
[ 94825.764] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: Adding scrollwheel support
[ 94825.764] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[ 94825.764] (**) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[ 94825.764] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0/0003:046D:C077.005D/input/input103/event4"
[ 94825.764] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech USB Optical Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 9)
[ 94825.764] (II) evdev: Logitech USB Optical Mouse: initialized for relative axes.
[ 94825.764] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[ 94825.764] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[ 94825.764] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[ 94825.764] (**) Logitech USB Optical Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
```

What other investigations / solutions can you suggest? I can provide additional info on request.

**ADDITIONAL INFO**

- both mouse and keyboard are wired not wireless and are plugged directly
- also freezes if I use the 2 USB SS ports.
- 15G swap (none used)
- 1T HDD (70% used)
- X.Org X Server 1.18.4
- xserver-xorg-input-evdev 1:2.10.1-1ubuntu2
- kernel 4.11.0-041100rc7-generic

**UPDATE 1**
After fiddling with restarting lightdm and plugging the mouse / keyboard in differetn usb ports they started working again. This doesn't always happen though.

**UPDATE 2**
Switching to HWE has helped somewhat in that the mouse and keyboard would become usable again if I switched USB ports making the system almost entirely usable until today when switching ports didn't help.

Comment: Is your Logitech USB dongle plugged into a computer USB port, or to a USB hub? Have you done the firmware upgrade for the Logitech USB dongle? Also... how much RAM? how much swap? SSD or HDD? Please start new comments directed to me with `@heynnema`or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema both mouse and keyboard are wired not wireless (this is a desktop) and are plugged directly. Also no difference if I use the 2 USB SS ports. I have 15G swap (none used), 1T HDD (70% used). How do I do the "firmware upgrade" for my device?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I thought that you were using wireless keyboard/mouse. In that case, check your BIOS for a USB setting. It could say "legacy" or "USB 3 support", etc. Try changing it from whatever it's set to, to "legacy" or "compatible" and see if that fixes the problem. Do you have USB 3 ports? What are "USB SS ports"? Report back.

Comment: Hi @heynnema, I couldn't find any USB settings in BIOS other than enabling disabling ports (e.g. enable/disable USB 3, enable/disable front ports). And yes by USB SS I mean USB 3.

Comment: Well, it's always possible that you've got a defective keyboard or mouse. Do you have another that you can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I strongly doubted it would help I've decided to also try replacing the mouse and keyboard (with same make and model).

This has immediately fixed the problem.

Seven months have passed and everything still works without a problem.