# Z8350 + Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Freeze

Tags: lubuntu, freeze

I have a [Zotac MiniPC](https://www.zotac.com/us/product/mini_pcs/pi223) with Intel Z8350 (cherry trail) inside

To run it with full power on Lubuntu 16.04.3 (got min == max 480 MHz on benchmark) I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761706/ubuntu-15-10-and-16-04-keep-freezing-randomly) and set the boot parameter  `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` in `/etc/default/grub`. So minipc works fine with 1440MHz... but if I start mkl Linpack benchmark it freezes.
I also did the same with Z8300 (Zotac PI221) and it works fine for me

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Lubuntu 17.10 fixes this problem - no more freeze