# Random freeze while playing video

Tags: drivers, grub2

System is completely locked with no mouse or keyboard, so unable to ctrl + alt F1 F2 etc.

I made some changes recommended in [Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04 keep freezing randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761706/ubuntu-15-10-and-16-04-keep-freezing-randomly)

> 1. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
> 2. There is a line in that: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` (like this), replace with: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet
>      splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"`
> 3. Save it (CTRL+O)
> 4. `sudo update-grub`
> 5. `sudo reboot`

This helped a great deal but did not solve the problem completely.

Some information about my system below:

This is a Pocket PC made by a Chinese company UDP

`sudo swapon --show`

```
NAME           TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/mmcblk0p3 partition 7.9G   0B   -1
```

`free -h`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        2.7G        3.5G        577M        1.6G        4.2G
Swap:          7.9G          0B        7.9G


NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
```

`uname -a`

```
4.12.0-rc2+ #261 SMP Tue Aug 8 19:02:00 CST 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`lshw -c video`

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 34
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:299 memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:80000000-9fffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

`lspci -vnn | grep VGA -A 12`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:22b0] (rev 34) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:7270]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 299
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 80000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=512M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [b0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=07 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```