# Ubuntu 16.0.4.3 is freezing after some time of usage

Tags: 16.04, nvidia

My machine which is running on Ubuntu 16.0.4.3 is freezing after some time of usage. I tried most of the solutions from [Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04 keep freezing randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761706/ubuntu-15-10-and-16-04-keep-freezing-randomly) and nothing seemed to help.

My laptop is **HP R007tx with 2gb nvidia 820M graphics card**

Answer (score 0):

It is thermal issue. In other words your computer's CPU get over heated. Install `Psensor` and watch the temperature of your CPU. Also try to listen to the fan and check if it rotates well without any over noise.