# Kubuntu 17.10: Flickering and Freezing

Tags: kubuntu, 17.10, plasma

I just updated to Kubuntu 17.10 from 17.04. During the initial install, the desktop would not load. After some work in the root shell (including using `dpkg` to fix some issues, I got the desktop GUI back up.

Now, the screen seems to be flickering and hanging at random intervals, and seemingly just with the focused application. As I write this, the entire screen will freeze from time to time, save for the mouse cursor.

Is anyone else experiencing a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had found this one on AskUbuntu and it worked for me on 16.04:

[Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04 keep freezing randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761706/ubuntu-15-10-and-16-04-keep-freezing-randomly)

I have applied it on Kubuntu and stopped freezing at all but get from time to time freeze but gets back again. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.  To improve it, could you summarize exactly what you did: there are 5 answers.  Which one did you apply?

Comment: Adding the “intel_idle.max_cstate=1”