# Ubuntu 16.04 freezing frequently

Tags: 16.04, freeze

I tried everything in the thread [Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04 keep freezing randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761706/ubuntu-15-10-and-16-04-keep-freezing-randomly) but still my machine keeps randomly freezing, after a while. It is usually when mozilla firefox is open. Please help me out. It's been just a month since I started using ubuntu.

Comment: Install Sysinfo from the default Ubuntu repositories and check if all your computer's RAM is recognized. If it isn't recognized there is a bad RAM stick.

Comment: @karel I've never used memtester from the grub menu but would that be a viable option too?

Comment: Yes, memtester and/or memtest86+ from the grub menu would be a viable options.

Comment: It sound quite strange. Did you properly complete all the steps in the thread you mentioned?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 keeps freezing (nvidia)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030466/ubuntu-18-04-keeps-freezing-nvidia)

Comment: This question was submitted well before the questions it is listed as a duplicate of. This question should be left open.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron I closed voted this question because it was only relevant to a very specific period of time. It has no answers, and the OP hasn't visited this site for more than 3 years. 16.04 was on topic when this question was asked, but it's 2021, and  by reasonable standards this is an abandoned question now.