# intel_idle.max_cstate=1 Intel Bay freeezing workaround no longer working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: kernel, freeze, 18.04

I have Intel Pentium N3540. It's known that Bay Trail line of CPUs has a system freeze bug which has so far been solvable by appending intel_idle.max_cstate=1 into a certain line of GRUB config, but this has stopped working since upgrading to 18.04.

Do you guys have any ideas why is it the case and if it is somehow fixeable? Thanks.

Comment: referencing this question https://askubuntu.com/a/796484/525195 for older versions of Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

According to comment# 1013 in [bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051) it is now fixed:

> I haven't checked this thread in a long time, but I thought I should
>   post my findings just in case it is of any use to anyone.
>
> A low end computer powered with an Intel N2807 which never worked more
>   than 30 mn without crashing when I didn't set ...max_cstates=1 now
>   works perfectly well with a stock kernel v. 5.3.1 or 4.19.75. I ran it
>   for a couple of days with each version without any issues. The average
>   power consumption was also down by a little over 10%.

It has taken about four years to fix this bug first reported December 8, 2015.