# Any kind of Copy+Paste freezes Ubuntu up

Tags: 18.04, kernel, nautilus, gnome-shell, freeze

My OS randomly freezes up frequently. Almost always its after a copy+paste however small the file is. The freezing is filesystem agnostic. Even a copy within home folders causes this issue.

System details:
Ubuntu 18.04.4, Gnome 3.28.2, kernel 5.3.0-62-generic #56~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP
installed on the HDD in a system with Windows on SSD.

Can somebody please point to any resolution ?

I have tried resolutions from the following links:

1. [Editing swappiness. Currently set to 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness)
2. [Checked kernel version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036748/recently-installed-ubuntu-18-04-but-it-keeps-freezing)
3. [Edited sysctl.conf](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397249/system-freezes-unresponsive-unusable-when-copying-large-file-to-usb)
4. [SysRq+REISUB only allows me to reboot. "REISU" do not work](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/563833/ubuntu-freezes-crashes)
5. [HDD seems fine from smartmon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487346/ubuntu-18-04-is-freezing-randomly)

Comment: Has it been like this since you first installed it, or did it develop recently?

Comment: Its been like this since the install.