# Dual Monitor - One outputs from graphics card and other from the motherboard

Tags: multiple-monitors, motherboard

I tried to do a dual monitor setup on ubuntu 16.04, the monitor connected to the graphics card worked, but the motherboard one didn't.
By the way, it works perfectly on windows, and when I shutdown, the monitor connected to the motherboard displays the ubuntu logo, just like the other one, can someone help me?

Motherboard: GIGABYTE GA-B150M-D3H
Graphics card: AMD R7 260x

thanks anyway xD

Comment: open menu search for display settings, see if the monitor is not turned on in the display settings?

Comment: It it detects the monitor, but nothing appears on the screen

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/777303/installing-intel-graphics-driver-in-ubuntu-16-04 and/or https://askubuntu.com/questions/980203/how-to-install-the-latest-intel-graphics-driver-in-ubuntu-17-10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Intel graphics driver in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777303/installing-intel-graphics-driver-in-ubuntu-16-04)