# How to Install the latest Intel Graphics Driver in Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: graphics, 17.10, intel

I was trying this but get errors:
[installing-intel-graphics-driver-in-ubuntu-16-04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777303/installing-intel-graphics-driver-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Error message:

```
Checking if Intel graphics card available...
  • checking for i915 module in /sys/module
  • i915 module found
Checking if Intel graphics card available... OK
Retrieving information from 01.org...
  • fetching https://download.01.org/gfx/ilg-config.cfg
  • saving to /home/sujan/.ilg-config
  • fetched 1626 bytes
  • fetched 9818 bytes
  • fetched 12301 bytes
  • looking up [Ubuntu artful] configuration
Retrieving information from 01.org... OK
Checking distribution... Failed
```

Comment: Intel® Graphics Update Tool v2.0.6 for Ubuntu* 17.04, 64-bit

Comment: Where did you get the Intel® Graphics Update Tool for *17.04*? I'm just able to find the one for *16.04*, and as you're using Artful (it seems) of course the distribution check fails for both of them. What's your actual question?

Comment: here is the url:
https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.6

@dessert Just I need to install Intel Graphics driver on my Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: May I ask *why* you want to install this driver? What's the problem?

Comment: currently my PC using an alternative driver for Intel graphics card.
But Intel graphics driver is available so I want to use this one.

Comment: Well, as you see the proprietary driver Intel provides is for 17.04, not 17.10 – I doubt you can work around that. If there's no problem just stick with the free alternative you currently use.

Comment: Historically, Intel drivers have been buggy.  For great Linux video, you had to go with nVidia.  ATI usually works.  I would love to see Intel get their act together because my current system is forcing me to use Intel video, which works well enough with the default drivers.  A lot better than it used to.  I don't do any 3D, or when I do, it's pretty sparkly.

Comment: graphics tool is deprecated https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/update-tool

Answer (score 9):

Until now Intel doesn't offer support for Ubuntu 17.10. I'm using updated drivers from `ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers` with 2 external monitors, so far without any problems on integrated graphic:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 vga 
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 [8086:5912] (rev 04)
        Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation HD Graphics 630 [1849:5912]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
```

You can install [Updated and Optimized Open Graphics Drivers](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) from PPA repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Comment: Did you have to do any thing else to apply the new drivers? I ran those two commands but don't notice a difference

Comment: @protoEvangelion Sorry, there's also `apt upgrade -y` command missing.

Comment: Also worked with Ubuntu 18.04. Maybe add sudo apt dist-upgrade -y. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Just change temporarily `/etc/lsb-release` to correspond to Zesty Zapus, it will work fine.

First, make backup

```
sudo cp /etc/lsb-release /etc/lsb-release.backup
```

Then edit the file

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/lsb-release
```

Replace contents with:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=zesty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 17.04"
```

When you are done installing the tool and the drivers, simply revert the changes:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/lsb-release
sudo cp /etc/lsb-release.backup /etc/lsb-release
```

Comment: I have fetched an error.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1csQOCtV5BEZIJowjXX4itygEsO5JcTn0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You didn't follow the instruction on the  [download page](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.6), you need to install signatures.
Here is how, run:

`wget https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-GROUP-KEY-ilg` and `sudo apt-key add RPM-GPG-GROUP-KEY-ilg`

Comment: It worked for me after installing the signatures, I think it should be added in the main answer, but you know better.

Comment: or `apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 611B903CAB97EA77`

Answer (score 2):

Up to now Intel haven't provided a graphics driver for 17.10, the latest version of the [Intel graphics update tool for Linux](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.6) is v2.0.6 for Ubuntu 17.04 and this software obviously doesn't work for Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: I don't believe that offer support for 17.10 even today. They have released  their 2017Q3 INTEL GRAPHICS STACK RECIPE but I don't believe thats made it over to 17.10 yet

Comment: And 17.04 isn't supported anymore by Canonical... Last time I tried I had Release notes file error