# HP Compaq locks up since upgrading to 18.04 LTS

Tags: boot, 18.04, hp

I was using the previous LTS for several years with no problem, but after I upgraded to 18.04 LTS it locks up on boot. I can boot it okay in safe mode but the graphics suck.

I'm not completely sure what model of HP Compaq it is but the CPU is an Intel Core2 Duo CPU E6750 @ 2.66GHz * 2.

`sudo lshw -C video` (from [How do I find out the model of my graphics card?](https://askubuntu.com/a/280836/59832)) gives me:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 82Q35 Express Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f0100000-f017ffff ioport:1230(size=8) memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f00fffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

How can I diagnose this problem? I already tried this answer to [How to Install the latest Intel Graphics Driver in Ubuntu 17.10?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1006155/59832)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the instructions in [DebuggingKernelBoot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelBoot) and saw:

> started user manager for uid 123

as the last message before it locked. Searching for this led me to [Ubuntu 18.04 hangs on booting with message “started user manager for uid 120” on Asus 1015PX](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037922/ubuntu-18-04-hangs-on-booting-with-message-started-user-manager-for-uid-120-on) which linked to a solution in [17.10 to 18.04 upgrade freezes during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036242/17-10-to-18-04-upgrade-freezes-during-boot) - look for "Update #7" in the question:

> Turns out that the problem isn't a gdm3 vs lightdm problem. It's a
>   gdm3/wayland problem with older Intel GPU's. To fix...
>
> In terminal...
>
> ```
> cd /etc/gdm3 # change directory
> sudo pico custom.conf # edit this file
> ```
>
> Find and change:
>
> ```
> #WaylandEnable=false
> ```
>
> To this:
>
> ```
> WaylandEnable=false
> ```
>
> Save the file.
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3 # select gdm3 DM
> ```
>
> Select gdm3 and OK.
>
> ```
> reboot # reboot the computer
> ```